# How to prefetch code for multiple pages from one page request in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js, client-side

Using client-side navigation I can navigate between pages using only JavaScript. The first request of a page takes some time to render and then the navigation back to it is nearly instant. During that first render that page only loads what’s necessary for it. That isolates each page making them independent. I just want to know, if there is a way to load the code for more than one page on a single request.

As an example, let's say I have multiple profile pages for a user (info, settings, history). I want to load the code for all of those pages on one request for any of those pages, so the navigation between them will be instant, and there will be no waiting time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the links (using [`next/link`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link)) to those pages are within the viewport the pages will be prefetched by default when in production mode (prefetch doesn't work in dev mode, though).

> `prefetch` - Prefetch the page in the background. Defaults to `true`.
> Any `<Link />` that is in the viewport (initially or through scroll)
> will be preloaded. Prefetch can be disabled by passing
> `prefetch={false}`. When `prefetch` is set to `false`, prefetching will
> still occur on hover. Pages using [Static Generation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props) will preload JSON
> files with the data for faster page transitions. **Prefetching is only enabled in production**.

If you're not using `next/link` to navigate to those pages, then you can use [`router.prefetch`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerprefetch) to force the prefetch.

> `router.prefetch(url, as)`
>
> - `url` - The URL to prefetch, including explicit routes (e.g.
>   `/dashboard`) and dynamic routes (e.g. `/product/[id]`)
> - `as` -
>   Optional decorator for `url`. Before Next.js 9.5.3 this was used to
>   prefetch dynamic routes, check our [previous
>   docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/tag/v9.5.2/api-reference/next/link#dynamic-routes)
>   to see how it worked

Comment: but what if I have a large amount of data and I want to navigate right after the page was rendered?

Comment: Prefetching will occur in the background as the page gets loaded.

Comment: this is the actual problem. What if it doesn't have time to fully prefetch the page? I want to find a way to load the javascript for multiple pages at once. In the docs, it is said: `A user opens their browser and navigates to your-blog.com/posts/first-post. What JavaScript is initially loaded for this page?` and the response: `JavaScript for the entire application is loaded.`. What if I want to, lets say load the javascript not only for the *first post*, but for the *home* page too

Comment: Again, as I said, using prefetch will do what you want. Simply having a `next/link` to the home page in `/posts/first-post`, or forcing the prefetch with `router.prefetch('/home')` will prefetch the JS code for that page too when `/posts/first-post` page gets loaded.